# Binary WebSockets in Play 2.xx

Tags: java, javascript, websocket, playframework-2.0, content-type

At my wits end scrawling the internet, I cannot seem to find anyway to deal with `play.mvc.WebSocket` with `Byte`,`Byte[]` or `ByteBuffer` ( which admittedly which doesn't support `Serialization`).

I've had plenty of success transmitting data using either of the two Generic types below:

```
WebSocket<String> getMetaData(){...}
WebSocket<JsonNode> getMetaData(){...}
```

but any-time I shove my own type in there, I receive the following error:

> Cannot use a method returning play.mvc.WebSocket[< MyType >] as an Handler

If I'm brutally honest, I always expected the transfer to be binary anyway, but using Browser inspectors, it shows the data being shifted across as plain text.

Anyone know how I can deal in just binary/bytes? Thanks.

(**Long term goal**: I'm trying to obtain an [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ArrayBuffer?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays/ArrayBuffer) on the JavaScript side while minimising amount of data transferred. )

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this?

```
WebSocket<byte[]> getMetaData(){...}
```